# Loop elements and check if class exists javascript

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop

I have 3 select option. I can get them in this way:

```
var theSelect = $("#id_"+portletId+"_ .selectpicker");
```

and the results is:

```
0:select#_Name_zeroid.form-control.selectpicker.completed
1:select#_Name_firstid.form-control.selectpicker.completed
2:select#_Name_secondid.form-control.selectpicker
```

as you can see 2 of these select have the attributes `completed` . How can I loop these and get a simple `console.log()` if the attribute `completed` exists?

Comment: please share the dom

Comment: That's not an attribute, that's a class. If you want all elements that also have the class `completed`, just add it after `.selectpicker`

Comment: using this: const theSelect = $("#id_"+portletId+"_ .selectpicker").filter(".completed");  it shows the same i've wrote before

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `classList` DOM attribute which has a `contains` method which takes a string and returns a boolean.

Or you can use jQuery

Native

```
document.querySelectorAll(".selectpicker").forEach(node => node.classList.contains("completed"));
```

jQuery

```
// filter the results
const theSelect = $("#id_"+portletId+"_ .selectpicker").filter(".completed");
```

Comment: Well, if i write a console.log() of theSlect it returns all 3 select. so, it's not what i want because it returns the same of what i've wrote in my question